# How can I get the impedance matrix of the network?

Tags: python, pandapower

Is there any way to calculate impedance matrix of the network in pandapower?

Comment: I'm sure there is.

Comment: Show what you have tried so far (code) and be specific about which part is giving you trouble. Read: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I ve searched readthedocs of the specified package but wasnt able to find a proper function or method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching in  [GitHub/Issues](https://github.com/e2nIEE/pandapower/blob/develop/tutorials/internal_datastructure.ipynb) I came up with this:

> Nodal Admittance Matrix:

```
Ybus = net._ppc["internal"]["Ybus"].todense()
```

While the

> Jacobian Matrix:

```
J = net._ppc["internal"]["J"].todense()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).